# Found new requirement not stated in initial question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I posted a question but realized there was more to it than I thought. A lot of answers are now invalid because the detail was not included. What should I do? I would delete it and make a new question but it says I can't delete now that there are answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why do you need to delete it? Accept the answer that best solves the initial question, then create a new question that incorporates your new requirements (and any ideas you've learned from the existing answers to avoid anyone duplicating effort). The initial question still might be useful to other readers that don't have your additional requirements, even if it is no longer 100% relevant to you.

Oh, and don't go bug answerers of the other question to go look at your new question. If they found your first question, they'll find your second one, too.

Comment: In that case can I undo my last edit so there is still the initial question?

Comment: I don't know anything about your specific question or your edit. If you added new requirements that weren't there when the initial answers you posted, then yes, I would roll back that edit.

Comment: How do you roll back the edit?

Comment: Click on the timestamp for the edit under the question, this should show the revisions, there should be an option to roll back to each revision. That said, depending on the complexity of your new requirement, it might be ok to just let the answerers know via a comment that you've added a new requirement. It may be simple for them to change their answer to handle the new requirement. My answer is based on the assumption that the answers no longer make sense because of the new requirement you've added.